# Quicksort partition does not work for odd input

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I'm trying to implement Quick Sort on my own, according to Cormen's Introduction to Alghorithms.
I have a following code, but also a problem with it:

```
void quickSort(Node* left, Node* right) {
    Node* start = left;
    Node* cur = left->next;

    if (left == right) return;

    while (cur != right) {
        if (start->data < cur->data) swap(start->data,cur->data);
        cur = cur->next;
    }

    swap(left->data,cur->data);

    Node* oldCur = cur;
    cur = getPrevious(cur);
    if (cur != nullptr && (getPrevious(left) != cur) && (cur->next != left)) quickSort(left,cur);

    cur = oldCur->next;
    if (cur != nullptr && (getPrevious(cur) != right) && (right->next != cur)) quickSort(cur, right);
}
```

For an even length it works correctly

```
7 6 5 8 4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

but for an odd number of input data, output looks like follows

```
7 6 5 8 4 2 1 
1 2 5 4 6 7 8
```

I suppose there is a problem somewhere in the partition part of algorithm, but I couldn't find it.

**EDIT**

I have probably found a problem and modified algorithm a bit. Right now I can't find any counterexample for it, but if someone see anything wrong please point it out :-)

```
void quickSort(Node* left, Node* right) {
    Node* start = left;
    Node* cur = left;
    T pivot = start->data;

    if (left == right) return;
    if (left->next == right) {
        if (right->data < left->data) swap(left->data,right->data);
        return;
    }

    swap(start->data,right->data);

    while (cur != right->next) {
        if (cur->data < pivot) {
            swap(cur->data,start->data);
            start = start->next;
        }
        cur = cur->next;
    }

    swap(right->data,start->data);

    quickSort(left, start);
    if (start->next != nullptr) quickSort(start->next, right);
}
```

Comment: Why not step through the code in a debugger and see for yourself what's going on there?

Comment: I'd suggest first rewriting it to look more like canonical quicksort: check if done. if not: partition(), quicksort(), quicksort(). If you're not done, you should always make 2 recursive calls and I can't follow why both of yours are checked.

Comment: I agree with NPE: if it is for your learning, debug it yourself, this you will learn the most. If it is intended to be used in some real code, use `std::sort` instead.

Comment: I have to ask, was this really the intent of the assignment? Quicksort I understand, but *value* swapping? Somewhat the point of a dynamic node list is that you don't *have* to value-swap: you rearrange pointers. I.e values always stay in their `Node` and only what points to each node changes. I know it doesn't address your question(s), but maybe review that assignment again and make *sure* the intention wash't linked list manipulation rather than simple value-swapping. I'd hate to see you kill yourself solving a problem for a solution that wasn't correct in the first place.

Comment: @NPE, I have been doing it for some time, but without success. After a little break I "rerun" my algorithm with a paper and a pencil and found a possible problem.

@WhozCraig, on my `Node` implementation, I store only a _pointers_ to data and to _next_, so _value_ swapping is in fact just a _pointer_ swap. I consulted with my PhD and this kind of list manipulation is okay, as the assignment is just about quicksort, not about advanced listed list learning.